# UWP Using Prism ViewModel & Interfaces Binding stops working

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, prism

This is all working well. When I click a button a border elements visibility is toggled.

In my XAML code behind:

```
Test2ViewModel ViewModel => DataContext as Test2ViewModel;
public Test2Page()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

And my ViewModel as:

```
public class Test2ViewModel : ViewModelBase,ITest
{
    private bool _borderIsVisible;
    public bool borderIsVisible
    {
        get => _borderIsVisible;
        set { SetProperty(ref _borderIsVisible, value); }
    }

    public Test2ViewModel()
    {
        borderIsVisible = true;
    }
    public void ToggleVisibility()
    {
        if (borderIsVisible)
        {
            borderIsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            borderIsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button
        Grid.Row="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.ToggleVisibility}"
        Content="Click Me" />
    <Border
        Grid.Row="1"
        Width="250"
        Background="AliceBlue"
        BorderBrush="Blue"
        BorderThickness="4"
        Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.borderIsVisible, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

When I try to implement an interface like this it stops working:

```
ITest ViewModel => DataContext as Test2ViewModel;
```

The app runs but the visibility binding stops working, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiled `{x:Bind}` checks whether the type that is bound is `INotifyPropertyChanged` so that it can wire up the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event used for data binding. However, as `x:Bind` is evaluated at compile-time, it cannot do so, because `ITest` does not derive from `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

To fix this, you will need to make sure `ITest` extends `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
interface ITest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Awesome Sir.That makes total sense.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) , happy coding!